# MySQL Query Database

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables Student and Takes

Student : ID, name, dept_name

Takes: ID, course_id, grade

I need to find the ID and name of each student, and their total number of credits taken but do not count where student got an F grade.

This is where I am at so far, but it is wrong in that it will grab a single student name, and total up all the credits as being that students.

```
select student.ID, student.name, count(course_id) AS credits
FROM student, takes
WHERE student.ID = takes.ID and takes.grade != 'F';

results
ID     name   credits
001     stud1   20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the count per student you need to `GROUP BY` the Student (`s.ID, s.name`):

```
SELECT s.ID, s.name, COUNT(*) AS credits
FROM student AS s
INNER JOIN takes AS t ON s.ID = t.ID 
WHERE t.grade != 'F'
GROUP BY s.ID, s.name
```

I am guessing that certain courses amount for more credits than others.  So if you have a field that shows how many credits each course is, you may want to link that table and use `SUM(CreditVal)` instead of `COUNT(*)`. Something like:

```
SELECT s.ID, s.name, SUM(c.credits) AS TotalCreditsEarned
FROM student AS s
INNER JOIN takes AS t ON s.ID = t.ID 
INNER JOIN course AS c ON c.ID = t.course_id
WHERE t.grade != 'F'
GROUP BY s.ID, s.name
```

In the above query just change `c.ID = t.course_id` to whatever the fields are that link the two tables together.

Comment: You're correct, I also have a course table with a credits column.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your query like

```
select s.ID, s.name, count(t.scourse_id) AS Total_Credits
FROM student s join takes t
on s.ID = t.ID and t.grade != 'F'
group by s.id;
```